# Trouble in assembly language using atod macro in visual studio

Tags: assembly, macros

If I’m not mistaken the macro appears to be working as one of any two numbers is swapping with the other. However the second digit swapped results in garbage output. For example, user enters 4 then 5. The swap should output the first number as 5 then 4. In this case 4 is just junk numbers.

```
.586
.MODEL FLAT

INCLUDE io.h            ; header file for input/output

.STACK 4096

.DATA 

number1 DWORD ?
number2 DWORD ?

prompt1 BYTE "Enter the first number", 0
prompt2 BYTE "Enter the second number", 0

stringIn BYTE 20 DUP (?)

outputNum1Lbl BYTE "The first number you entered", 0
input1 BYTE 11 DUP (?), 0
outputNum2Lbl BYTE "The second number you entered", 0
input2 BYTE 11 DUP (?), 0
swapNum1Lbl BYTE "The new first number is", 0
newNum1 BYTE 11 DUP (?),0
swapNum2Lbl BYTE "The new second number is", 0
newNum2 BYTE 11 DUP (?), 0

.CODE
_MainProc PROC
    input prompt1, stringIn, 20
    atod stringIn
    mov eax, number1

    input prompt2, stringIn, 20
    atod stringIn
    mov number2, ebx

    xchg eax, ebx
    dtoa newNum1, ebx
    dtoa newNum2, eax

    output swapNum1Lbl, newNum1
    output swapNum2Lbl, newNum2

    mov eax, 0
    mov ebx, 0
    ret
_MainProc ENDP

END                             ; end of source code
```

Comment: Where does atod put its result? In eax, I guess? So you need to store eax to the appropriate variable after each call. It doesn't magically know that you want the value in ebx for the second call, so it is going to put it in eax. Also, take care with the order of operands, you have them reversed. The value of eax is probably going to be overwritten by any of these macros (input, atod, and dtoa), so don't try to keep a value in the register across one of the macros.

Comment: `mov eax, number1` loads eax from memory.  That's definitely not right; you probably got the operands backwards there.  Single-step your code in the debugger.

Comment: Also, `xchg` isn't a macro, it's an x86 instruction.  Most of the other stuff is macros, so you could disassemble your executable to see what will actually run.  (Or single-step by instructions.)

Comment: Atod only puts results in eax, so digesting the registers at each point in the code the first input is over written by the second input. I just need to copy what’s in eax after input 1 into another register before I ask for a second input

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to use the memory variables in this code. Just store the first input in the `EBX` register and leave the second input in the `EAX` register.

```
input prompt1, stringIn, 20
atod stringIn
mov ebx, eax

input prompt2, stringIn, 20
atod stringIn

xchg eax, ebx
push eax
dtoa newNum1, ebx
pop  eax
dtoa newNum2, eax
```

Because "dtoa" will probably clobber `EAX`, you could choose to save it on the stack temporarily.

---

> "The new first number is"
>
> "The new second number is"

These labels are somewhat misleading!

---

The definitions of "dtoa" and "atod"

```
dtoa        MACRO  dest,source         ; convert double to ASCII string
            push   ebx                 ; save EBX
            lea    ebx, dest           ; destination address
            push   ebx                 ; destination parameter
            mov    ebx, [esp+4]        ; in case source was EBX
            mov    ebx, source         ; source value
            push   ebx                 ; source parameter
            call   dtoaproc            ; call dtoaproc(source,dest)
            add    esp, 8              ; remove parameters
            pop    ebx                 ; restore EBX
            ENDM

atod        MACRO  source              ; convert ASCII string to integer in EAX
            lea    eax,source          ; source address to AX
            push   eax                 ; source parameter on stack
            call   atodproc            ; call atodproc(source)
            add    esp, 4              ; remove parameter
            ENDM
```

Comment: That's a hilariously clunky `dtoa` macro.  Would be so much easier to `push eax` / `push source` / `lea eax, [dest]` / `mov [esp+8], eax` / call / add.  Or just require the caller to pass an address instead of a dereferenced address (e.g. `offset newNuw1` or `edi` instead of `[edi]`, so you could `push dest`.  (Or does `push source` not assemble without a size override if it's a memory operand?  And `push dword ptr ebx` isn't valid either?